# How to notify user of new activity?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I've build a activity stream using the [Public Activity](https://github.com/chaps-io/public_activity/issues) gem for my rails/angular app, and I've set up a follow system where users can follow each other. So when a user that the current user is following does a action (add a movie to his watchlist) it will create a activity record and that activity will show up in the current user his activity stream. I would like to notify the current user that there's been a new activity.

To display the activities I've created a icon,

```
%i.fa.fa-bell{"ui-sref" => "home.activities"}
```

I would like to give this icon another class, like `newActivities` when there are new activities.

So I have to differentiate between old and new messages. For that I was thinking to add a column called `viewed` to the activities table. When a new activity is created the `viewed` column is empty. And when the icon to show the activities is clicked it adds a value to the `viewed` column.

On the angular side I would go through the activies scope (that has all the current users activities), see if there are activities with an empty `viewed` value, if so, add the `.newActivities` class to the icon.

Or is there perhaps an easier, and or better way to achieve this result?

Comment: Seems sensible to me as is.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone comes acros this question, or maybe someone can improve on my method. But let me show you what I did.

First off I created a `viewed` string in my activities model,

```
class AddViewedToActivities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :activities, :viewed, :string
  end
end
```

Then I set the default to 'uncheck'

```
class AddDefaultToViewedInActivities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column_default(:activities, :viewed, 'uncheck')
  end
end
```

Run db:migrate etc.

Then on the Angular side I've created a activities controller,

```
activitiesService.loadActivities().then(function(response) {
  $scope.activities = response.data;

  var activities = $scope.activitie
  var init = function(){
    var hasValue = activities.some(function(obj) { return obj.viewed == "uncheck" });

    if (hasValue == true){
      checked = true ;
      $scope.newActivities = 'newActivities'
    }
  }

  $scope.viewActivities = function (){

    angular.forEach(activities, function (activitie) {
      if (activitie.viewed == 'uncheck'){
        viewActivities.update({
          viewed: `check`,
          id:      activitie.id
        }).then(init);
      }
    });
    $scope.newActivities = '';

  }
  init();
})
```

The init function check if there's an object that equals "uncheck". If it's true it adds the class "newActitivites to $scope.newActivities` ng-class (the icon that shows if there's a new message)

The $scope.viewactivities`is a function that fires when a user checks his new activities. It checks each activitie and finds the new ones, with the value of`uncheck`. Then it updates that record with check so that next time the user comes back, all his activities have been checked and the icon doesn't change.

For completion sake here's the activities service,

```
app.factory('viewActivities', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    update: function(activitie) {
      return $http.put('/activities/' +activitie.id + '.json', activitie);
    }
  };
}])
```

The activities controller in rails,

```
def update
  @activity = PublicActivity::Activity.find(params[:id])
  @activity.update_attributes(activity_params)
  redirect_to :root
end
```

And you have to set this in your routes,

```
resources :activities, only:    [:create, :destroy, :index, :show, :update, :put]
```